# Explicacion CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER y json_decode

Tags: php

tengo este codigo y la funcion curlopt_httpheader no encuentro como funciona como tal, se que hace una cabecera personalizada pero hasta ahi llego.

El json_decode no entiendo que saque el resultado de la salida de cURL

```
$cURL = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: aplication/json'));
$res = curl_exec($cURL);
$obj = json_decode($res, true);
```

Comment: Hola. No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el problema o duda?

Comment: El metodo httpheader no entiendo su funcionalidad, y la parte del array nose que hace.

Y luego no entiendo por que para sacar $obj hace un json_decode de $res con un true

Comment: Está explicado en el Manual de PHP. Leer sobre [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php), no es un *método*, sino una de las opciones de configuración, básicamente sirve para configurar el header HTTP mediante un array de campos. También, leer sobre [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), básicamente es una forma de obtener la respuesta de la petición cURL, en ese caso la convertirá en un array, debido a que le pasas `true` en el 2º parámetro.

Comment: El encabezado [*Accept*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) es para indicarle al servidor "Acepto (o entiendo) el [tipo MIME](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) json", que por cierto esta mal escrito, `application` es con doble "p".